# Strange bug in insertion sort in python

Tags: python, debugging, sorting, insertion-sort

I don't know if the language, data type, or my algorithm has something to do with it, but I get this strange bug with my insertion sort written in python. I was writing it in preparation for a potential exam question tomorrow, and it works, but it only seems to work for numbers >= 1. I will demonstrate the output given two different inputs:

```
#Insertion Sort
#Has some weird bug; only works for numbers >= 1.
def insertion(arr):
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        m = arr[i]
        for x in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            if(arr[x] > m):
                arr[x+1] = arr[x]
            else:
                arr[x+1] = m
                break
    return arr
```

The following is a set of inputs given to the function:

```
l1 = [1,3,7,2,5,8,4,6]
l2 = [1.1,3.7,7.0,2.5,5.1,8.3,4.0,7.9,6.0]
l3 = [1,3,7,2,5,8,0,4,6]
l4 = [1.1,3.7,7.0,2.5,5.1,8.3,4.0,7.9,6.0,0.3]
```

The following is a list of outputs with respect to the above inputs

```
n1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n2 = [1.1, 2.5, 3.7, 4.0, 5.1, 6.0, 7.0, 7.9, 8.3]
n3 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n4 = [1.1, 1.1, 2.5, 3.7, 4.0, 5.1, 6.0, 7.0, 7.9, 8.3]
```

It seems that the sort function will move values < 1 all the way down to the beginning, but then replaces them with the lowest value in the list. I thought this was a very strange bug, but don't really have time right now to work on figuring it out (finals begin next week, as we are on the quarter system). I thought perhaps someone here would like to work on solving it. It may simply be an error in my logic, but I find it strange that it works perfectly for all values 1 or greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if `m` is smaller than every element in the array `arr` before it, you never set `arr[0] = m`.  If the `arr[x] > m` case always holds true, then you never set any entry in `arr` to `m`. So you'll get all the way to the front, copy the first element into the second position (with `arr[x+1] = arr[x]` when `x` is 0), but never actually insert `m` at the 0-th position with `arr[0] = m`.  One (perhaps unusual) way to do this is to use Python's `for... else` construction, where the `else` case gets called if you never `break` out of the `for` loop:

```
def insertion(arr):
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        m = arr[i]
        for x in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            if(arr[x] > m):
                arr[x+1] = arr[x]
            else:
                arr[x+1] = m
                break
        else:
            arr[0] = m
    return arr
```

Comment: Nice catch. As soon as I read your first sentence, I realized my mistake.